# interpretation of loop in R - simulation of Poisson variable

Tags: r, for-loop, simulation

I'm trying to understand the below loop which uses the table-look up method to simulate 5000 observations from the Poisson distribution.

I don't understand why t is initialised as -1 here.

The use of while is confusing here since t only has 2 values, 1 and -1.

If u smaller than f then t=1 and xi=?
If u greater than f then t=-1 and xi=0.
I would appreciate if someone could explain me this loop.

```
 n=5000 #sample size
 lambda=8 #parameter
 u=runif(n)
 x=0
 for(i in 1:n){
    t=-1
    g=exp(-lambda) # P(X =0)
    f=g # P(X ≤0)
    x[i]=0
  while(t<0){
       if(u[i]<f)
          t=1
       else{ 
          x[i]=x[i]+1
          g=g*lambda/x[i] # P (X =i)
          f=f+g 
            }
        }
    }# P(X≤i)
   x
```

Comment: The `t`-variable is just a flag to stop the while-loop when `f` is greater than `u[i]`.

Comment: Could you go through an example ?

Comment: It could be `t = -200` or any other number less than 0 because the loop is checking that `t<0`. As soon as `u[i] <f` is true `t` is set to 1 and the `while` condition is no longer met and the for loop goes to the next value of `i`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @BondedDust said, `t` is a flag that indicates whether the while loop should continue or end.

As an example to see how it works you can change your sample to n=3.

```
n=3 #sample size
lambda=8 #parameter
u=runif(n)
x=0
for(i in 1:n){
    cat ("i=" , i, '\n')
    t=-1
    g=exp(-lambda) # P(X =0)
    f=g # P(X ≤0)
    x[i]=0
    while(t<0){
        cat ("    t=" , t, '\n')
        cat ("    g=" , g, '\n')
        cat ("    f=" , f, '\n')
        cat ("    u[i]=" , u[i], '\n')
        cat ("    x[i]=" , x[i], '\n')
        cat("     ", u[i] < f, '\n')

        if(u[i]<f)
            t=1
        else{ 
            x[i]=x[i]+1
            g=g*lambda/x[i] # P (X =i)
            f=f+g 
        }

    }
}# P(X≤i)
```

So if you run that and look at the dumps you see that `f` is monotonically increasing (g has to be positive and great than 0). So eventually u[i] will be less than `f` and the flag is set to 1, the comparison is true, and the `while` is finished. (But remember that it is a `while`.)